# How to vertically center a button in a panel?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to vertically center a button in a the body of a panel. I have tried a bunch of css suggestions on stack overflow and the button will still not move. I want the button to be centered next to the image.

[image]

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <p>Panel Heading</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-body">
          <div class="col-lg-2 button">
            <button id="fix_button" type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"> Fix</span> </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-offset-3"> <img src="users/1479318868.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="300px"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle with css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **CSS Flexbox**. Make your `.panel-body` a flex container use flex's center properties.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.panel-body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Horizontally centers the content */
  align-items: center; /* Vertically centers the content */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <p>Panel Heading</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-body">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 button">
                        <button id="fix_button" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"> Fix</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive" width="300px">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to make it work creating a new html document but in my project it still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @LR07 Maybe your old project have something missing. I can help you if I can have access to your old code. Not a a big deal, if its working on your new project it really good. If this answer really works for you please accept this answer.

Comment: When I created a new file called "bootstrap2.css" the changes were applied. But when I copy and paste "boostrap2.css" into my original "bootstrap.css" the changes don't work. Do you know what the issue with that is?

Comment: @LR07 You need to show me the code, I can't help you out without seeing the code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add the code. It's going to look a little messy. <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">. First I copied my the css file into a new one called boostrap2.css, when I change the href link to "css/bootstrap2.css" the changes are applied and the button is aligned.

Comment: I also have this in my header: <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: @LR07 No luck though. It will be good if you can post your code to jsfiddle, codepen, etc. and you gave me a link of it, so that I can see your code.

Comment: it's ok i'll figure it out

Comment: @Saurave Rastogi I found the problem. The css changes weren't showing because I had to clear the cache in chrome. Thanks again

Comment: @LR07 Oh! thats irritating... ;)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
.panel-body { display: flex; align-items: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
button{
    height:20px; 
    width:100px; 
    margin: -20px -50px; 
    position:relative;
    top:50%; 
    left:50%;
}
```

for just horizontal alignment use either

```
button{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or

```
div{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help